# How to fetch related user info when fetching all posts in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hello I am new to MongoDB. I want to fetch all posts with user details of who created the post. I have two collections.

users collection:

```
[{
   "_id": {
     "$oid": "655d897b794e33f8ae0e2377"
   },
   "name": "kunal",
 },
 {
   "_id": {
     "$oid": "655d897b794e33f8ae0e237b"
   },
   "name": "Amit",
 }]
```

user_posts collection

```
[{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "655d897b794e33f8ae0e2378"
    },
    "user_id": "655d897b794e33f8ae0e2377",
    "post_name": "Test Post Group",
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "655d897b794e33f8ae0e2379"
    },
    "user_id": "655d897b794e33f8ae0e2377",
    "post_name": "Test Post Group",
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "655d897b794e33f8ae0e237a"
    },
    "user_id": "655d897b794e33f8ae0e2377",
    "post_name": "Test Post 3",

  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "655d897b794e33f8ae0e237c"
    },
    "user_id": "655d897b794e33f8ae0e237b",
    "post_name": "Test Post Amit",
  }]
```

In the users collection, `_id` is an `ObjectId` but in the user_posts collection, `user_id` is not an `ObjectId`. But I don't want to make `user_id` as `ObjectId`.

I tried below query:

```
db.user_posts.aggregate([
  {
    '$lookup' : {
      'as' : 'user_info',
      'from' : 'users',
      'foreignField' : '_id',
      'localField' : 'user_id'
    }
  }
]).pretty();
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a8"),
    "post_name": "Test Post",
    "user_id": "655c3285822c4a52150c30a7",
    "user_info": []
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30a9"),
    "post_name": "Test Post 2",
    "user_id": "655c3285822c4a52150c30a7",
    "user_info": []
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("655c3285822c4a52150c30aa"),
    "post_name": "Test Post 3",
    "user_id": "655c3285822c4a52150c30a7",
    "user_info": []
  }
]
```

This above query only works if makes `user_id` as an `ObjectId` at the schema level. May be needed to convert `user_id` to an `ObjectId` in the run-time query itself. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

https://mongoplayground.net/p/qPQGN2VCH8-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ensure that the values must be in the same type for matching/comparison. Reference: [Join Conditions and Subqueries on a Joined Collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection)

```
db.user_posts.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "let": {
        user_id: {
          $toObjectId: "$user_id"
        }
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$user_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "user_info"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playgrund](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nea4oOAFSLB)

Comment: Thank you. Its working ... what does that mean $$user_id ??

Comment: `$$user_id` represents the variable with name `user_id` which is declared in `let`. To get the variable value, you need the `$$` prefix followed by the variable name.

Comment: i have one doubt...  is it ok i dont want to make user_id as object .. is it any perfomance issue?.. or is it mandatory to make user_id as object?,,,  Its better you can give some your inputs as i am beigner

Comment: Performance issues will depend on the (how big) size of the collection and the number of documents that need to be returned (there also other factors as well such as utilize index etc). Will recommend making the `user_id` as `ObjectId`, so you can use your original `$lookup` and save the cost for performing the data conversion.

Comment: Actually i am using Laravel Framework (PHP) where many type of relationships are there Like belongsTo, HasMany, if make user_id as object these relationship are fail and dont give results.

Comment: I see, hmmm, at this moment I guess stick to the original type better as it has the dependencies. In case you meet performance issue, you should utilize the index, restrict the returned data (pagination) etc.

Comment: One more point, the object you keep mentioning for `user_id` is actually `ObjectId`. `ObjectId` is not the same with object. [`ObjectId`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#std-label-objectid`)

Comment: so the schema is fine that i am using currently?